# How to format a JSON date without \ / Date?

Tags: c#, serialization

I need format JSON date from this format: docDate":"1360905419116", ","inDocDate":"1360905419116", ect.

My serialize:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string result = jsonSerializer.Serialize( new {
    docDate = DateTime.Now,
    inDocDate = DateTime.Now,
    outDocDate = DateTime.Now } );
```

The result I receive after serialization:

```
{"docDate":"\/Date(1360905419116)\/","inDocDate":"\/Date(1360905419116)\/","outDocDate":"\/Date(1360905419116)\/"}
```

I want to have

```
{"docDate":"1360905419116","inDocDate":"1360905419116","outDocDate":"1360905419116"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension method

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
  internal static readonly long DatetimeMinTimeTicks = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).Ticks;

  public static long ToJsTime(this DateTime dateTime)
  {
    return (dateTime.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - DatetimeMinTimeTicks) / 10000L;
  }
}
```

So you code become:

```
string result = jsonSerializer.Serialize( new {
    docDate = DateTime.Now.ToJsTime().ToString(),
    inDocDate = DateTime.Now.ToJsTime().ToString(),
    outDocDate = DateTime.Now.ToJsTime().ToString() } );
```